# Shouldn't HTTP GET request append name=value pairs to the URL?

Tags: html, forms, http, https

I just started learning HTML a couple of weeks ago and I'm confused about forms.

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) MDN article, the HTTP GET method appends the name=value pairs to the URL so I tried to prove it.

I signed in on [lichess.org](https://lichess.org/login) but I don't see any query string either in the URL bar or using Chrome's devtools.
[image]

Questions:

What's happening?

Shouldn't HTTP GET append name=value pairs to the URL?

Is this due to the HTTPS protocol?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you `inspect` the form on [lichess.org](https://lichess.org/login) you notice the method is set as `POST` so no querystring will be generated when the form is submitted. Creating the querystring reveals a potential vulnerabilty if the form is used for particular purposes - the resultant URL can be bookmarked, edited, replayed etc. You would use `GET` typically for a `search` type feature where perhaps it is beneficial to be able to bookmark the URL - to share for instance. 
The `https` protocol has nothing to do with the issue in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't inspect the form. So if the form uses POST, why is GET in the headers section?

Comment: When you load the page initially there is a GET request. The form should be submitted using POST - enable the `preserve log` feature in console tools (network), load the page and submit the form

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you *submit* forms, and this form has `method="POST"`